# Bounty box appears to scroll to the right when text should just auto-wrap

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, user-interface

I have set up a bounty on a question to reward an existing answer, and found that the "custom message" box behaves strangely on Firefox 19.0.2 on OS X.

When typing, as the cursor gets close to the right-hand side of the textarea, the whole modal div appears to scroll to the right, when in fact JS shouldn't be doing anything - the text cursor should just auto-wrap in the textarea automatically.

[image: Screenshot of incorrectly scrolled modal div]